# How do i create function to sort args in a list

Tags: javascript

Hello i would like to create something for sort args in the list by how many times they are in the list

all arguments are separated with one `;`

```
let list = "abcd1; abcd4; abcd4; abcd9; abcd2; abcd5"
```

the list can be 5 args long like 100 or 243.

i think it can work with two for loops one to see if the i element is duplicated and compare the array[i] with the array[j] and you could use a temporary array to create the object then later reassign to the main array.

but don't know how to do it.

Comment: What did you already try? You clearly first need to create a array from string etc. One array with unique values and one with all the results. Then you can use two loops where you use the unqique values to count the times that value is in the not unique values. Anyway, where not going to give it to you. You probably would use function like split(), filter() and find() for this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your list

```
let list = "abcd1; abcd4; abcd4; abcd9; abcd2; abcd5"
```

2. Create a new list by splitting the string at ';'

```
let newList = list.split(';')

// newList = ["abcd1", " abcd4", " abcd4", " abcd9", " abcd2", " abcd5"]
```

3. Declare an empty object and iterate through all elements of new list and add them as keys to the object. Set the value as 1 if the key is not present in the object, else add 1 to the value if key is present.

```
let obj = {}

for (let i of newList) {
    let newI = i.trim() // trim() to remove spaces or new line characters 

    // check if newI is already present in the object, i.e. we've seen it before
    // if that's the case then it must have a value so increment that value by 1
    if (newI in obj) {
        obj[newI] += 1
    }

    // if newI is not present in the object then we're seeing it for the first time.
    // so set its value as 1
    else {
        obj[newI] = 1
    }
}

// obj = {abcd1: 1, abcd4: 2, abcd9: 1, abcd2: 1, abcd5: 1}
```

4. Get the keys of the object in an array and finally sort that array while sending the value in the object ``obj``` as comparison parameter. As we want to sort by how many times that value appears in the string.

```
let arr = Object.keys(obj)

// arr = ["abcd1", "abcd4", "abcd9", "abcd2", "abcd5"]

arr.sort((a, b) => obj[a] - obj[b])

// arr = ["abcd1", "abcd9", "abcd2", "abcd5", "abcd4"]
```

Sorted from least number of appearances in string to maximum number of appearances